# fancybox - small underscore beside every picture

Tags: html, fancybox-2

I'm new to html coding and coding overall. I've made an website where I've used fancybox 2.1.4 to make an album. Everything on the website works fine, except that it is an small underscore beside every picture in the album. Why is this and how can I remove it?

[link to my website](http://kattinilzen.se/)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not actually an underscore, you have `text-decoration: underline`. Removing that got rid of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you show what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually an underscore, you have `text-decoration: underline`, removing that got rid of it.

You could modify your css to set the text-decoration to none.

```
fancybox {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an underscore, it is the underline created by the surrounding link. You can remove the underline on those links with the following CSS declaration:

```
a.fancybox {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```